# IntelliJ cannot run my TestNG project

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, testng, appium

I have a maven project with TestNG. I used to use Eclipse and moved to IntelliJ today and think I configured all correctly.
But when I run the project in IntelliJ, it cannot be run with below error messages.
It runs without any problem when running with maven command 
`mvn test`.

But when running from IntelliJ, I get:

> @w@C:\Users\sdymj\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp
>   -temp C:\Users\sdymj\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp [TestNG] Running:   D:\Work\SW Engineering\WFC-Test\testng.xml

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:227)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:55)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:72)
at com.samsung.wfctest.TestStart.setUp(TestStart.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

---- code ----

```
@BeforeSuite (alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    // DesiredCapability delivers all the necessary info to Appium server
    // so that Appium server can handshake with the device and handle it properly
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "DUT");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, Util.WAIT_TIME);
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", Util.TARGET_PACKAGE); // 
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", Util.TARGET_ACTIVITY);

    // below codes are only for N OS - works find without these in M OS
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb uninstall io.appium.settings");
    process.waitFor();
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb uninstall io.appium.unlock");
    process.waitFor();

    // create Appium server session
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(Util.APPIUM_URL), cap);

    util = new Util();
}
```

--------import classes----------

```
package com.samsung.wfc;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
```

----------- pom.xml --------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.samsung</groupId>
<artifactId>WFCTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-BETA1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>wfctest</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

--------- testng.xml -----------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.samsung.wfc.TestStart"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: This is probably a dependency issue. please add your pom.xml and your imports in the test class.

Comment: Please show us your testng.xml file.

Comment: I added pom.xml, imports and testng.xml, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This was the reason.. it was set to "Android API" and I changed to the first option "1.8" and somehow it worked.

[image: Project SDK confugration view from IntelliJ]